# How can I rebind the action taken by reflinks?

Tags: front-end, customization

I'm playing with building a different way to move through doc pages and I want to use a custom function when clicking on a ref-link. How can I do this without pre-processing my entire notebook?

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to set the `ButtonBoxOptions` for the `"Link"` style. For instance we could make a custom stylesheet that would look like the standard reference sheet, but use a different lookup function:

```
Notebook[{
 Cell[
  StyleData[
   StyleDefinitions->
    FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb",
     CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"
     ]
   ]
  ],
 Cell[StyleData["Link"],
  ButtonBoxOptions->{
   ButtonFunction:>
    Function[
     KernelExecute[helpBrowserPacletLookup[EvaluationNotebook[],#]]
     ],
   Evaluator->"Local"
   }
  ]
 }]
```

Now `helpBrowserPacletLookup` will be called instead of the standard lookup function. Note that this technique can be used for *any* style of hyperlink as they all work as `ButtonBox`-es.